# vue.js - Test watchers of v-autocomplete

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vuetify.js, v-autocomplete

I have a vue.js SearchTest component with a `v-autocomplete`. It has watchers for `select` and `search`:

```
// SearchTest.vue

<template>
  <v-autocomplete
    v-model="select"
    :items="items"
    :loading="isLoading"
    :search-input.sync="search"
    hide-no-data
    hide-selected
    placeholder="Type search query"
    return-object
  ></v-autocomplete>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    select: null,
    isLoading: false,
    search: null,
    items: [],
  }),
  watch: {
    select(val) {
      console.log('select: ', val);
    }
    search(val) {
      console.log('search: ', val);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

I'm testing it as following. I expect both watchers should fire. In fact, only the `select` watcher fired. The `search` watcher did not.

```js
// SearchTest.spec.js

import { createLocalVue, mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import SearchTest from '@/components/SearchTest.vue'

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

describe('SearchTest.vue', () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue();
  const vuetify = new Vuetify({});
  let spy;
  beforeAll(() => {
    spy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    spy.mockClear();
  })

  it('Select', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(SearchTest, { localVue, vuetify });

    // Triggers select.
    wrapper.vm.select = 'select';
    wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
      expect(spy).toBeCalled();  // OK
    });
  })

  it('Search', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(SearchTest, { localVue, vuetify });

    // Should trigger search, but fails.
    wrapper.vm.search = 'search';
    wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
      expect(spy).toBeCalled();  // Fail
    });
  })
})
```

Any idea for passing the `Search` test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what is happening, but I found that the `v-autocomplete` internally sets the search property to `null` on creation if no item is selected ([source](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/009d96968026b8fa0b89b1a9fadddf7b8c832f25/packages/vuetify/src/components/VAutocomplete/VAutocomplete.ts#L390)). It does so by using `this.$nextTick`, which I suppose causes problems when setting the search value inside the test. I found two ways to mitigate this:

### 1

Nesting the change of `search` and the assertion into another `$nextTick` seems to the trick.

```js
it('Search', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(SearchTest, { localVue, vuetify });

  wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
    wrapper.vm.search = 'search';
    wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
      expect(spy).toBeCalled();
    });
  });
})
```

### 2

For this solution I took the initialisation of `wrapper` and put it in `beforeEach`. It does basically the same but I guess the timing of the mounting of the component is different, so it doesn't collide with the `$nextTick` of `v-autocomplete`.

```js
describe('SearchTest.vue', () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue();
  const vuetify = new Vuetify({});
  let spy;
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(SearchTest, { localVue, vuetify });
  })

  beforeAll(() => {
    spy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    spy.mockClear();
  })

  it('Select', () => {
    // Triggers select.
    wrapper.vm.select = 'select';
    wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
      expect(spy).toBeCalled();  // OK
    });
  })

  it('Search', () => {
    // Should trigger search, but fails.
    wrapper.vm.search = 'search';
    wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
      expect(spy).toBeCalled();  // Fail
    });
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for me. The second solution is elegant and concise.